# PHPunit how to exclude all files in directory but not exclude subdirectories

Tags: phpunit, code-coverage

I have such problem. I want to exclude all files in SomeBundle\Entity but don't want to exclude SomeBundle\Entity\Repository and SomeBundle\Entity\Factory.

```
SomeBundle\Entity
SomeBundle\Entity\Repository
SomeBundle\Entity\Factory

SomeBundle\Entity\File1.php
SomeBundle\Entity\File2.php
SomeBundle\Entity\File3.php
```

I trying to do it with

```xml
    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>./../src/SomeBundle</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory suffix=".php">./../src/SomeBundle/Entity</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
```

but as a result, i exclude all in SomeBundle\Entity ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit colors="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Test Suite">
            <directory>SomeBundle</directory>
            <directory>SomeBundle/Entity/**</directory>
            <exclude>SomeBundle/Entity</exclude>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```